# encodeURIComponent in a unquoted HTML attribute

Tags: xss, javascript, html

My gut feeling is that the following should be attackable:

```
$("<td><a href=somefile.php?url="+encodeURIComponent(somevar)+">Download Here</a></td>");
```

In contrast to

```
$("<td><a href=\"somefile.php?url="+encodeURIComponent(somevar)+"\">Download Here</a></td>");
```

For a cross site scripting attack if the user has control over `somevar`, yet I can't seem to find the specific attack. Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 8):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent):

> `encodeURIComponent` escapes all characters except the following: alphabetic, decimal digits,
>
> `- _ . ! ~ * ' ( )`

You would normally require a space character to add another attribute (such as `onclick`), unfortunately this will be encoded as part of the URI.

However, from [OWASP XSS (Cross Site Scripting) Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet):

> Unquoted attributes can be broken out of with many characters, including
> `[space] % * + , - / ; < = > ^ and |`

So you might want to try the `-` or `*` characters to attempt to create a new attribute.

e.g. set `somevar` to `http://www.example.com-onclick=alert('xss')`
or `http://www.example.com*onclick=alert('xss')`

Your mileage may vary between browsers and unfortunately the `=` will still be URL encoded so you will also have that hurdle to overcome. So even though the value is not quoted nor encoded properly, it may not be possible to turn this encoding flaw into an XSS exploit.

Your second example is more secure, although the value should really be HTML encoded:

```
$("<td><a href=somefile.php?url=\""+htmlEscape(encodeURIComponent(somevar))+"\">Download Here</a></td>");
```

where [`htmlEscape`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7124052/413180) is:-

```
function htmlEscape(str) {
    return String(str)
            .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
            .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
            .replace(/'/g, '&#39;')
            .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
            .replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}
```